# Concurrent.futures vs Multiprocessing in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Python 3.2 introduced [Concurrent Futures](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), which appear to be some advanced combination of the older threading and [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) modules.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using this for CPU bound tasks over the older multiprocessing module?

[This article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/01/16/python-paralellizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-concurrent-futures/) suggests they're much easier to work with - is that the case?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

I wouldn't call `concurrent.futures` more "advanced" - it's a *simpler* interface that works very much the same regardless of whether you use multiple threads or multiple processes as the underlying parallelization gimmick.

So, like virtually all instances of "simpler interface", much the same trade-offs are involved:  it has a shallower learning curve, in large part just because there's so much less available *to* be learned; but, because it offers fewer options, it may eventually frustrate you in ways the richer interfaces won't.

So far as CPU-bound tasks go, that's way too under-specified to say much meaningful.  For CPU-bound tasks under CPython, you need multiple processes rather than multiple threads to have any chance of getting a speedup.  But how much (if any) of a speedup you get depends on the details of your hardware, your OS, and especially on how much inter-process communication your specific tasks require.  Under the covers, all inter-process parallelization gimmicks rely on the same OS primitives - the high-level API you use to get at those isn't a primary factor in bottom-line speed.

**Edit: example**

Here's the final code shown in the article you referenced, but I'm adding an import statement needed to make it work:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
def pool_factorizer_map(nums, nprocs):
    # Let the executor divide the work among processes by using 'map'.
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nprocs) as executor:
        return {num:factors for num, factors in
                                zip(nums,
                                    executor.map(factorize_naive, nums))}
```

Here's exactly the same thing using `multiprocessing` instead:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def mp_factorizer_map(nums, nprocs):
    with mp.Pool(nprocs) as pool:
        return {num:factors for num, factors in
                                zip(nums,
                                    pool.map(factorize_naive, nums))}
```

Note that the ability to use `multiprocessing.Pool` objects as context managers was added in Python 3.3.

As for which one is easier to work with, they're essentially identical.

One difference is that `Pool` supports so many different ways of doing things that you may not realize how easy it *can* be until you've climbed quite a way up the learning curve.

Again, all those different ways are both a strength and a weakness.  They're a strength because the flexibility may be required in some situations.  They're a weakness because of "preferably only one obvious way to do it".  A project sticking exclusively (if possible) to `concurrent.futures` will probably be easier to maintain over the long run, due to the lack of gratuitous novelty in how its minimal API can be used.

Comment: *"you need multiple processes rather than multiple threads to have any chance of getting a speedup"* is too harsh. If speed is important; the code might already use a C library  and therefore it can release GIL e.g., regex, lxml, numpy.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks for adding that - perhaps I should have said "under *pure* CPython", but I'm afraid there's no short way to explain the truth here without discussing the GIL.

Comment: And it worth mentioning that threads might be especially useful and enough when having operation with long IO.

Comment: @TimPeters In some ways `ProcessPoolExecutor` actually has more options than `Pool` because `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` returns `Future` instances that allow cancellation (`cancel`), checking *which* exception was raised (`exception`), and dynamically adding a callback to be called upon completion (`add_done_callback`).  None of these features are available with `AsyncResult` instances returned by `Pool.apply_async`. In other ways `Pool` has more options due to `initializer` / `initargs`, `maxtasksperchild`, and `context` in `Pool.__init__`, and more methods exposed by `Pool` instance.

Comment: @max, sure, but note that the question wasn't about `Pool`, it was about the modules.  `Pool` is a small part of what's in `multiprocessing`, and is so far down in the docs it takes a while for people to realize it even exists in `multiprocessing`.  This particular answer focused on `Pool` because that's all the article the OP linked to used, and that `cf` is "much easier to work with" simply isn't true about what the article discussed.  Beyond that, `cf`'s `as_completed()` can also be very handy.

Comment: @TimPeters oh yes completely agree

Comment: "without discussing the GIL": GIL is interesting :) Would it be possible to point to a link with the problems GIL runs into for threads? I seem to remember something but not much....

Answer (score 100):

Probably for most of the time when you need parallel processing, you will find that either the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from the `concurrent.futures` module or the `Pool` class from the `multiprocessing` package will provide equivalent facilities and it boils down to a matter of personal preference. But each does offer some facilities that make certain processing more convenient. I thought I would just point out a few:

**Submitting Multiple Tasks**

Each package has analogs to the built-in `map` and `itertools.starmap` functions. If you have a worker function that takes a single argument, then multiple tasks can be submitted using the `map` method with either package:

```py
def worker_function(x):
    # Return the square of the passed argument:
    return x ** 2

# multiprocessing.pool example:
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool() as pool:
    squares = pool.map(worker_function, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

# concurrent.futures example:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    squares = list(executor.map(worker_function, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
```

Note that the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` method returns a list while the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map` method returns an iterator just like the built-in `map` method.

Both `map` methods take a *chunksize* argument that batches submitted tasks into "chunks" that are pulled off the task input queue so that a pool process will process all the tasks in a chunk before getting the next chunk from the queue. This results in fewer but larger writes and reads to the input task queue. For large iterables being passed to the `map` method, chunking up the tasks can greatly improve performance.

If not specified the default *chunksize* value for `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` is 1, which is no chunking. For `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` the default value is `None`, which results in the class calculating a "suitable" *chunksize* based on the pool size and the number of elements in the passed iterable. At the time of this writing, the chunksize value is computed more or less as `int(math.ceil(iterable_size / (4 * pool_size)))`. When doing multithreading with these packages (discussed briefly later), the default *chunksize* value for both packages is 1.

If the worker function takes multiple arguments, it's a bit easier to work with the `concurrent.futures` package as its `map` method can be passed multiple iterables:

```py
def worker_function(x, y):
    return x * y

x_values = (1, 2, 3)
y_values = (9, -2, -8)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(worker_function, x_values, y_values))
```

We must use the `starmap` method with the `multiprocessing` package and the arguments must be "zipped" together if there are separate iterables for each argument:

```py
def worker_function(x, y):
    return x * y

x_values = (1, 2, 3)
y_values = (9, -2, -8)

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(worker_function, zip(x_values, y_values))
```

You do not have to use the `zip` built-in function if the arguments are already combined together as follows:

```py
def worker_function(x, y):
    return x * y

args = (
    (1, 9), # first x, y pair of arguments
    (2, -2),
    (3, -8)
)
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(worker_function, args)
```

**Getting Task Results Back As Soon As They Are Produced**

When submitting a batch of tasks, you sometimes want to be get the task results (i.e. return values) as soon as they become available. Both facilities provide for notification that a result from a submitted task is available via callback mechanisms:

Using `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def process_result(return_value):
    print(return_value)

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(worker_process, args=(i,), callback=process_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The same can be done, albeit awkwardly, using a callback with `concurrent.futures`:

```py
import concurrent.futures

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def process_result(future):
    print(future.result())

def main():
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = [executor.submit(worker_process, i) for i in range(10)]
    for future in futures:
        future.add_done_callback(process_result)
    executor.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here each task is individually submitted for which a `Future` instance is returned. Then the callback must be added to the `Future`. Finally, when the callback is invoked, the argument passed is the `Future` instance for the task that has been completed and method `result` must be called to get the actual return value. But with the `concurrent.futures` module, there is actually no need to use a callback at all. You can use the `as_completed` method:

```py
import concurrent.futures

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(worker_process, i) for i in range(10)]
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print(future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it is easy to tie the return value back to the original passed argument to `worker_process` by using a dictionary to hold the `Future` instances:

```py
import concurrent.futures

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(worker_process, i): i for i in range(10)}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            i = futures[future] # retrieve the value that was squared
            print(i, future.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`multiprocessing.Pool` has methods `imap` and `imap_unordered`, the latter which allows task results to be returned in *arbitrary order*, but not necessarily in completion order. These methods are considered to be a *lazier* version of `map`. With method `map`, if the passed *iterable* argument does not have a `__len__` attribute, it will first be converted to a `list` and its length will be used to compute an effective `chunksize` value if `None` was supplied as the *chunksize* argument. Therefore, you cannot achieve any storage optimizations by using a generator or generator expression as the *iterable*. But with methods `imap` and `imap_unordered`, the *iterable* can be a generator or generator expression; it will be iterated as necessary to produce new tasks for submission. But this necessitates that the default *chunksize* parameter be 1 since the length of the *iterable* in general cannot be known. But that doesn't stop you from providing a reasonable value using the same algorithm that the `multiprocessing.Pool` class uses if you have a good approximation to the length of the *iterable* (or the *exact* size as in the example below):

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    if iterable_size == 0:
        return 0
    chunksize, extra = divmod(iterable_size, pool_size * 4)
    if extra:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def main():
    cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
    N = 100
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(cpu_count, N)
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker_process, range(N), chunksize=chunksize):
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But with `imap_unordered` there is no way to easily tie a result with a submitted job unless the worker process returned the original call arguments along with the return value. On the other hand the ability to specify a `chunksize` with `imap_unordered` and `imap`, for which the results *will* be in a predictable order, should make these methods more efficient than invoking the `apply_async` method repeatedly, which is essentially equivalent to using a chunksize of 1. But if you do need to process results in completion order, then to be sure you should use method `apply_async` with a callback function. It does, however, appear based on experimentation that if you use a *chunksize* value of 1 with `imap_unordered`, the results will be returned in completion order.

The `map` method of the `ProcessPoolExecutor` is best compared to the `Pool.imap` method from the `multiprocessing` package because they have a couple of similarities and one significant difference. The similarities: First, this method will not convert its passed input *iterable* arguments that are generator expressions to lists in order to compute effective *chunksize* values and that is why the *chunksize* argument defaults to 1 and why, if you are passing large *iterables*, you should consider specifying an appropriate *chunksize* value. Second, the `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` method returns a result *iterable* that needs to be iterated to retrieve all the return values from the worker function and these results are available as soon as they have been generated with one difference: Unlike the `Pool.imap` method, the `ProcessPoolExecuter.map` method does not return its result *iterable* until all elements of the input *iterable* that was passed to it have been iterated and placed on the task queue, i.e. the input *iterable* is not *lazily* evaluated. It therefore follows that you cannot begin to retrieve results from the worker function until this occurs, even though many results might have been generated by the time that all input tasks have been iterated and queued up. And it also follows that if you have a situation where you can generate input faster than the worker function can generate its results, the input task queue storage requirements can get quite large.

**Submitting a Task and Blocking Until It Is Completed**

The `multiprocessing.Pool` class has a method `apply` that submits a task to the pool and blocks until the result is ready. The return value is just the return value from the worker function passed to the `apply` function. For example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker_process(i):
    return i * i # square the argument

def main():
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        print(pool.apply(worker_process, args=(6,)))
        print(pool.apply(worker_process, args=(4,)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` class has no such equivalent. You have to issue a `submit` and then a call to `result` against the returned `Future` instance. It's not a hardship to have to do this, but the `Pool.apply` method is more convenient for the use case where a blocking task submission is appropriate. Such a case is when you have processing that calls for threading because most of the work being done in the threads is heavily I/O except for perhaps one function that is very CPU bound. The main program that creates the threads first creates a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance and passes it as an argument to all the threads. When the threads need to call the heavily CPU-bound function, it now runs the function using the `Pool.apply` method thereby running the code in another process and freeing the current process to allow the other threads to run.

**Multiprocessing or Multithreading?**

A big deal has been made of the `concurrent.futures` module having two classes, `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` with identical interfaces. That is a nice feature. But the `multiprocessing` module also has an undocumented `ThreadPool` class with an identical interface as `Pool`:

```py
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
>>> dir(Pool)
['Process', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_check_running', '_get_sentinels', '_get_tasks', '_get_worker_sentinels', '_guarded_task_generation', '_handle_results', '_handle_tasks', '_handle_workers', '_help_stuff_finish', '_join_exited_workers', '_maintain_pool', '_map_async', '_repopulate_pool', '_repopulate_pool_static', '_setup_queues', '_terminate_pool', '_wait_for_updates', '_wrap_exception', 'apply', 'apply_async', 'close', 'imap', 'imap_unordered', 'join', 'map', 'map_async', 'starmap', 'starmap_async', 'terminate']
>>> dir(ThreadPool)
['Process', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_check_running', '_get_sentinels', '_get_tasks', '_get_worker_sentinels', '_guarded_task_generation', '_handle_results', '_handle_tasks', '_handle_workers', '_help_stuff_finish', '_join_exited_workers', '_maintain_pool', '_map_async', '_repopulate_pool', '_repopulate_pool_static', '_setup_queues', '_terminate_pool', '_wait_for_updates', '_wrap_exception', 'apply', 'apply_async', 'close', 'imap', 'imap_unordered', 'join', 'map', 'map_async', 'starmap', 'starmap_async', 'terminate']
>>>
```

Note that you can also perform multithreading with:

```py
# This Pool is a function with the same interface as the
# multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.__init__ initializer and returns a
# mulitprocessing.pool.ThreadPool instance:
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

**Submitting Tasks One at a Time and Timeouts**

You can submit single tasks with either `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit`, which returns a `Future` instance, or `Pool.apply_async`, which returns an `AsyncResult` instance, and specify a timeout value for retrieving the result:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
from time import sleep


def worker_1():
    while True:
        print('hanging')
        sleep(1)


def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as pool:
        future = pool.submit(worker_1)
        try:
            future.result(3) # kill task after 3 seconds?
        except TimeoutError:
            print('timeout')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("return from main()")
```

Prints:

```
hanging
hanging
hanging
timeout
hanging
hanging
hanging
hanging
hanging
hanging
hanging
etc.
```

The main process when calling `future.result(3)` will get a `TimeoutError` exception after 3 seconds because the submitted task has not completed within that time period. But the task is continuing to run, tying up the process and the `with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as pool:` block never exits and thus the program does not terminate.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
from time import sleep


def worker_1():
    while True:
        print('hanging')
        sleep(1)

def main():
    with Pool(1) as pool:
        result = pool.apply_async(worker_1, args=())
        try:
            result.get(3) # kill task after 3 seconds?
        except TimeoutError:
            print('timeout')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("return from main()")
```

Prints:

```
hanging
hanging
hanging
timeout
return from main()
```

This time, however, even though the timed-out task is still continuing to run and is tying up the process, the `with` block is not prevented from exiting and thus the program terminates normally. The reason for this is that the context manager for the `Pool` instance will execute a call to `terminate` when the block exits and this results in the immediate termination of all processes in the pool. This is contrasted with the context handler for the `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance, which executes a call to `shutdown(wait=True)` to await the termination of all processes in the pool when the block it governs exits. The advantage would seem to go to `multiprocessing.Pool` if you are using context handlers to handle pool termination and the possibility of a timeout exists. Update: In Python 3.9, a new argument, *cancel_futures*, has been added to the `shutdown` method. Consequently, you can terminate any tasks waiting to run (but not tasks already executing) if you explicitly call `shutdown(cancel_futures=True)` instead of relying on the default behavior resulting from the implicit call to `shutdown` when using a context handler.

But since the context handler for `multiprocessing.Pool` only calls `terminate` and not `close` followed by `join`, you must then ensure that all the jobs you have submitted have completed before exiting the `with` block, for example by submitting jobs with a blocking, synchronous call such as `map` or calling `get` on the `AsyncResult` object returned by a call to `apply_async` or iterating the results of the call to `imap` or by calling `close` followed by `join` on the pool instance.

Although there is no way to exit until timed-out tasks complete when using the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, you can *cancel* the starting of submitted tasks that are not already running. In the following demo we have a pool of size 1 so that jobs can only run consecutively. We submit 3 jobs one after another where the first two jobs take 3 seconds to run because of calls to `time.sleep(3)`. We immediately try to cancel the first two jobs. The first attempt of canceling fails because the first job is already running. But because the pool only has one process, the second job must wait 3 seconds for the the first job to complete before it can start running and therefore the cancel succeeds. Finally, job 3 will begin and end almost immediately after job 1 completes, which will be approximately 3 seconds after we started the job submissions:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def worker1(i):
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Done', i)

def worker2():
    print('Hello')

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        t = time.time()
        future1 = executor.submit(worker1, 1)
        future2 = executor.submit(worker1, 2)
        future3 = executor.submit(worker2)
        # this will fail since this task is already running:
        print(future1.cancel())
        # this will succeed since this task hasn't started (it's waiting for future1 to complete):
        print(future2.cancel())
        future3.result() # wait for completion
        print(time.time() - t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
False
True
Done 1
Hello
3.1249606609344482
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.

Comment: My main takeaway after reading this: Pythons parallel execution APIs are a mess and there are dozens of ways of doing the same thing and it is really hard to find the right class+method combination. Zen 13 is a joke by now.

Comment: Very detailed, consider using subheadings to highlight the major points.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to other answers' detailed list of differences, I've personally run into a unfixed (as-of 2022-11-20) [indefinite hang that can happen with multiprocess.Pool](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/66587) when one of the workers crashes in certain ways. (In my case, an exception from a cython extension, though others say this can happen when a worker gets a SIGTERM, etc.) According to [the documentation for ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), it has been robust to this since python 3.3.

Answer (score 5):

I love `concurrent.futures`, mainly because the iterator of multiple function parameters: `multiprocessing` is somehow hacky when it comes to obtain multiple arguments to a function (there is no `istarmap()`-equivalent of `starmap()`):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def power_plus_one(x, y):
    return (x**y) + 1

def wrapper(t):
    return power_plus_one(*t)

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    r = list(pool.imap(wrapper, [(0, 1), (2, 2)]))

print(r)
```

I find `imap()`/`imap_unordered()` super helpful for progress bars like [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) or time estimations for larger computation. In `concurrents.futures`, this is super handy:

```
def power_plus_one(x, y):
    return (x**y) + 1

o = dict() # dict for output

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(power_plus_one, x, y): (x, y) for x, y in [(0, 1), (2, 2)]}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        i = futures[future]
        o[i] = future.result()
print(o)
```

I also love the handy result mapping as a dict. :)

With tqdm you can easily:

```
for future in tqdm(concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures), total=len(futures)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I faced a lot of issues with the multiprocessing module as compared to concurrent.futures.(But this was on Windows os)

Two of main differences i could see were:

1. Frequent Hangs in the multiprocessing module
2. Concurrent.futures has got a relatively simpler way of execution. Meaning fetching the results, tracking of child processes etc.is very simple.

Example: (Fetching the result)

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    f1 = executor.submit(some_function, parameter_to_be_passed) 
    print(f1.result())
```

So if you returning any value from `some_function()` you can directly catch/store it using `f1.result()`. The very same thing will need additional steps in the "multiprocessing" module.

If you are running on Linux systems then the hangs might not occur but the execution complexity is still more in the "multiprocessing" module.

Also having said this, it is also important to note my tasks were highly CPU intensive tasks.

On a personal note, I would recommend concurrent.futures.

Comment: Frequent hangs? That's a fairly unspecific statement. Could it be your code? Also `multiprocessing.pool` requires no "additional" steps: `async_result = pool.submit(some_function, args=(parameter1, parameter2, ...)); print(async_result.get())`

Answer (score 0):

`concurrent.futures` give you more control, for example:

```
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2021/10/19 10:37

import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing.pool
import random
import threading
import time


def hello(name):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return f"Hello {name} {threading.current_thread()} "


print("ThreadPool:")
pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(4)
for args, result in pool.imap_unordered(lambda x: (x, hello(x)), range(10)):
    print(args, "=>", result)

print("\nThreadPoolExecutor:")
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
futures = {executor.submit(hello, x): x for x in range(10)}
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    print(futures[future], "=>", future.result()
```

Example output:

```
ThreadPool:
1 => Hello 1 <DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 29700)>
0 => Hello 0 <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 29688)>
2 => Hello 2 <DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 19680)>
6 => Hello 6 <DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 19680)>
3 => Hello 3 <DummyProcess(Thread-4, started daemon 33028)>
4 => Hello 4 <DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 29700)>
5 => Hello 5 <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 29688)>
9 => Hello 9 <DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 29700)>
8 => Hello 8 <DummyProcess(Thread-4, started daemon 33028)>
7 => Hello 7 <DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 19680)>

ThreadPoolExecutor:
0 => Hello 0 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 30764)>
1 => Hello 1 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 36220)>
2 => Hello 2 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2, started daemon 13120)>
4 => Hello 4 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 30764)>
3 => Hello 3 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3, started daemon 30260)>
8 => Hello 8 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3, started daemon 30260)>
5 => Hello 5 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 36220)>
6 => Hello 6 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2, started daemon 13120)>
7 => Hello 7 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 30764)>
9 => Hello 9 <Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3, started daemon 30260)>
```

Comment: Downvote due to lack of explanation.