# Python multiprocessing with start method 'spawn' doesn't work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wrote a Python class to plot pylots in parallel. It works fine on Linux where the default start method is fork but when I tried it on Windows I ran into problems (which can be reproduced on Linux using the spawn start method - see code below). I always end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 50, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 7, in test
    asyncPlotter.saveLinePlotVec3("test")
  File "test.py", line 41, in saveLinePlotVec3
    args=(test, ))
  File "test.py", line 34, in process
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

C:\Python\MonteCarloTools>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\adrian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 82, in steal_handle
    _winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, source_pid)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I hope there is a way to make this code work for Windows. Here a link to the different start methods available on Linux and Windows: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
def test():

    manager = mp.Manager()
    asyncPlotter = AsyncPlotter(manager.Value('i', 0))

    asyncPlotter.saveLinePlotVec3("test")
    asyncPlotter.saveLinePlotVec3("test")

    asyncPlotter.join()


class AsyncPlotter():

    def __init__(self, nc, processes=mp.cpu_count()):

        self.nc = nc
        self.pids = []
        self.processes = processes


    def linePlotVec3(self, nc, processes, test):

        self.waitOnPool(nc, processes)

        print(test)

        nc.value -= 1


    def waitOnPool(self, nc, processes):

        while nc.value >= processes:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        nc.value += 1


    def process(self, target, args):

        ctx = mp.get_context('spawn') 
        p = ctx.Process(target=target, args=args)
        p.start()
        self.pids.append(p)


    def saveLinePlotVec3(self, test):

        self.process(target=self.linePlotVec3,
                       args=(self.nc, self.processes, test))


    def join(self):
        for p in self.pids:
            p.join()


if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `spawn` start method, the `Process` object itself is being pickled for use in the child process.  In your code, the `target=target` argument is a bound method of `AsyncPlotter`.  It looks like the entire `asyncPlotter` instance must also be pickled for that to work, and that includes `self.manager`, which apparently doesn't want to be pickled.

In short, keep `Manager` outside of `AsyncPlotter`.  This works on my macOS system:

```
def test():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    asyncPlotter = AsyncPlotter(manager.Value('i', 0))
    ...
```

Also, as noted in your comment, `asyncPlotter` did not work when reused.  I don't know the details but looks like it has something to do with how the `Value` object is shared across processes.  The `test` function would need to be like:

```
def test():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    nc = manager.Value('i', 0)

    asyncPlotter1 = AsyncPlotter(nc)
    asyncPlotter1.saveLinePlotVec3("test 1")
    asyncPlotter2 = AsyncPlotter(nc)
    asyncPlotter2.saveLinePlotVec3("test 2")

    asyncPlotter1.join()
    asyncPlotter2.join()
```

All in all, you might want to restructure your code and use [a process pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).  It already handles what `AsyncPlotter` is doing with `cpu_count` and parallel execution:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method
from random import random
import time

def linePlotVec3(test):
    time.sleep(random())
    print("test", test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_start_method("spawn")
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(linePlotVec3, range(20))
```

Or you could use a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) to do [pretty much the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776189/concurrent-futures-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3).  This example starts tasks one at a time instead of mapping to a list:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from random import random

def work(i):
    r = random()
    print("work", i, r)
    time.sleep(r)

def main():
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=ctx) as pool:
        for i in range(20):
            pool.submit(work, i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: For a second it looked like you saved my day, but unfortunately your solution works only when I call ```asyncPlotter.saveLinePlotVec3("test")``` once. If I call it twice in a row I get the same error again. I updated my code with your proposed changes adding the second call of ```asyncPlotter``` which still fails :/

Comment: @Adrian I edited my answer with some new code and a suggestion for another approach.  It seems that wrapping the multiprocessing code in a class is causing some rather murky issues with `multiprocessing`.  HTH

Comment: thanks for your help. I made it work by refactoring my code to use ```pool.map()```, it's not as nice because I have to collect all my input for all the plots I want to generate first in a list first and can't call the plotting function on the fly, but at least the code executes 10 times faster now :)

Comment: I posted another example that should be more flexible for your case.

Answer (score 1):

For portability, all objects passed as arguments to a function that will be run in a process must be picklable.

Comment: I pass only a string here to the function that runs in a process. So what is the problem here? And why does it work with the fork start method and not with spawn?