# Python JoinableQueue call task_done in other process need twice

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I have implemented a WorkerManager based on `multiprocessing.Process` and `JoinableQueue`. While I try to handle the process exceptions like timeout or un-handle exceptions after proc.join(timeout), and evaluate proc.exitcode to determine how to handle, and then call in_queue.task_done() to notify the job has done with the exception-handle logic. However it need to invoke twice. I have no idea why it should be called twice. Is there anyone could figure it out the reason here.

The whole code snippet:

```
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-

import time
import threading
from queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Event, Process, JoinableQueue, cpu_count, current_process

TIMEOUT = 3


class WorkersManager(object):

    def __init__(self, jobs, processes_num):
        self._processes_num = processes_num if processes_num else cpu_count()
        self._workers_num = processes_num
        self._in_queue, self._run_queue, self._out_queue = JoinableQueue(), JoinableQueue(), JoinableQueue()
        self._spawned_procs = []
        self._total = 0
        self._stop_event = Event()
        self._jobs_on_procs = {}

        self._wk_kwargs = dict(
            in_queue=self._in_queue, run_queue=self._run_queue, out_queue=self._out_queue,
            stop_event=self._stop_event
        )

        self._in_stream = [j for j in jobs]
        self._out_stream = []
        self._total = len(self._in_stream)

    def run(self):
        # Spawn Worker
        worker_processes = [
            WorkerProcess(i, **self._wk_kwargs) for i in range(self._processes_num)
        ]
        self._spawned_procs = [
            Process(target=process.run, args=tuple())
            for process in worker_processes
        ]

        for p in self._spawned_procs:
            p.start()

        self._serve()

        monitor = threading.Thread(target=self._monitor, args=tuple())
        monitor.start()

        collector = threading.Thread(target=self._collect, args=tuple())
        collector.start()

        self._join_workers()
        # TODO: Terminiate threads
        monitor.join(TIMEOUT)
        collector.join(TIMEOUT)

        self._in_queue.join()
        self._out_queue.join()
        return self._out_stream

    def _join_workers(self):
        for p in self._spawned_procs:
            p.join(TIMEOUT)

            if p.is_alive():
                p.terminate()
                job = self._jobs_on_procs.get(p.name)
                print('Process TIMEOUT: {0} {1}'.format(p.name, job))
                result = {
                    "status": "failed"
                }

                self._out_queue.put(result)
                for _ in range(2):
                    # NOTE: Call task_done twice
                    # Guessing:
                    # 1st time to swtich process?
                    # 2nd time to notify task has done?
                    # TODO: figure it out why?
                    self._in_queue.task_done()
            else:
                if p.exitcode == 0:
                    print("{} exit with code:{}".format(p, p.exitcode))
                else:
                    job = self._jobs_on_procs.get(p.name)
                    if p.exitcode > 0:
                        print("{} with code:{} {}".format(p, p.exitcode, job))
                    else:
                        print("{} been killed with code:{} {}".format(p, p.exitcode, job))

                    result = {
                        "status": "failed"
                    }

                    self._out_queue.put(result)
                    for _ in range(2):
                        # NOTE: Call task_done twice
                        # Guessing:
                        # 1st time to swtich process?
                        # 2nd time to notify task has done?
                        # TODO: figure it out why?
                        self._in_queue.task_done()

    def _collect(self):
        # TODO: Spawn a collector proc
        while True:
            try:
                r = self._out_queue.get()
                self._out_stream.append(r)
                self._out_queue.task_done()

                if len(self._out_stream) >= self._total:
                    print("Total {} jobs done.".format(len(self._out_stream)))
                    self._stop_event.set()
                    break
            except Empty:
                continue

    def _serve(self):
        for job in self._in_stream:
            self._in_queue.put(job)

        for _ in range(self._workers_num):
            self._in_queue.put(None)

    def _monitor(self):
        running = 0
        while True:
            proc_name, job = self._run_queue.get()
            running += 1
            self._jobs_on_procs.update({proc_name: job})
            self._run_queue.task_done()
            if running == self._total:
                break


class WorkerProcess(object):

    def __init__(self, worker_id, in_queue, run_queue, out_queue, stop_event):
        self._worker_id = worker_id
        self._in_queue = in_queue
        self._run_queue = run_queue
        self._out_queue = out_queue
        self._stop_event = stop_event

    def run(self):
        self._work()
        print('worker - {} quit'.format(self._worker_id))

    def _work(self):
        print("worker - {0} start to work".format(self._worker_id))
        job = {}
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            try:
                job = self._in_queue.get(timeout=.01)
            except Empty:
                continue

            if not job:
                self._in_queue.task_done()
                break

            try:
                proc = current_process()
                self._run_queue.put((proc.name, job))
                r = self._run_job(job)
                self._out_queue.put(r)
            except Exception as err:
                print('Unhandle exception: {0}'.format(err), exc_info=True)
                result = {"status": 'failed'}
                self._out_queue.put(result)
            finally:
                self._in_queue.task_done()

    def _run_job(self, job):
        time.sleep(job)
        return {
            'status': 'succeed'
        }


def main():

    jobs = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    procs_num = 3
    m = WorkersManager(jobs, procs_num)
    m.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the issue code as following:

```
   self._out_queue.put(result)
                    for _ in range(2):
                        # ISSUE HERE !!!
                        # NOTE: Call task_done twice
                        # Guessing:
                        # 1st time to swtich process?
                        # 2nd time to notify task has done?
                        # TODO: figure it out why?
                        self._in_queue.task_done()
```

I need to invoke the `self._in_queue.task_done()` twice to notify the JoinableQueue the job has done by the exception-handle logic.

I guess whether `task_done()` call 1st time was to switch process context? or anything else. according to the testing. the 2nd task_done() has effect.

```
worker - 0 start to work
worker - 1 start to work
worker - 2 start to work

Process TIMEOUT: Process-1 5
Process TIMEOUT: Process-2 6
Process TIMEOUT: Process-3 7
Total 5 jobs done.
```

If you call task_done() once, and it will block forever and not to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a race condition, defined as:

> A race condition arises in software when a computer program, to operate properly, depends on the sequence or timing of the program's processes or threads.

In method `WorkerProcess._work`, your main loop begins:

```
    while not self._stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            job = self._in_queue.get(timeout=.01)
        except Empty:
            continue

        if not job:
            self._in_queue.task_done()
            break
```

`self._stop_event` is being set by the `_collect` thread. Depending on where `WorkerProcess._work` is in the loop when this occurs, it can exit the loop leaving the `None` that has been place on the `_in_queue` signifying no more jobs. Clearly, this occurs twice for two processes. It could happen even for 0, 1, 2 or 3 processes.

The fix is to replace `while not self._stop_event.is_set():` with `while True:` and to just rely on finding `None` on the `_in_queue` to signify termination. This enables you to remove those extra calls to `task_done` for those processes that have completed normally (you actually only needed *one* extra call per successfully completed process instead of the two you have).

But that is half of the problem. The other half is you have in your code:

```
def _join_workers(self):
    for p in self._spawned_procs:
        p.join(TIMEOUT)
        ...
            p.terminate()
```

Therefore, you are not allowing your workers enough time to deplete the `_in_queue` and thus there is the possibility of an *arbitrary* number of messages being left on it (in the example you have, of course, there would be just the current "job" being processed and the `None` sentinel for a total of 2).

But this is the problem in general with the code: it has been over-engineered. As an example, referring back to the first code snippet above. It can be further simplified to:

```
    while True:
        job = self._in_queue.get() # blocking get
        if not job:
            break
```

Moreover, there is no reason to even be using a `JoinableQueue` or `Event` instance since the use of a `None` sentinel placed on the `_in_queue` is sufficient to signify that the worker processes should terminate, especially if you are going to be prematurely terminating the workers. The simplified, working code is:

```
import time
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count, current_process

TIMEOUT = 3


class WorkersManager(object):

    def __init__(self, jobs, processes_num):
        self._processes_num = processes_num if processes_num else cpu_count()
        self._workers_num = processes_num
        self._in_queue, self._run_queue, self._out_queue = Queue(), Queue(), Queue()
        self._spawned_procs = []
        self._total = 0
        self._jobs_on_procs = {}

        self._wk_kwargs = dict(
            in_queue=self._in_queue, run_queue=self._run_queue, out_queue=self._out_queue
        )

        self._in_stream = [j for j in jobs]
        self._out_stream = []
        self._total = len(self._in_stream)

    def run(self):
        # Spawn Worker
        worker_processes = [
            WorkerProcess(i, **self._wk_kwargs) for i in range(self._processes_num)
        ]
        self._spawned_procs = [
            Process(target=process.run, args=tuple())
            for process in worker_processes
        ]

        for p in self._spawned_procs:
            p.start()

        self._serve()

        monitor = threading.Thread(target=self._monitor, args=tuple())
        monitor.start()

        collector = threading.Thread(target=self._collect, args=tuple())
        collector.start()

        self._join_workers()
        # TODO: Terminiate threads
        monitor.join()
        collector.join()

        return self._out_stream

    def _join_workers(self):
        for p in self._spawned_procs:
            p.join(TIMEOUT)

            if p.is_alive():
                p.terminate()
                job = self._jobs_on_procs.get(p.name)
                print('Process TIMEOUT: {0} {1}'.format(p.name, job))
                result = {
                    "status": "failed"
                }

                self._out_queue.put(result)
            else:
                if p.exitcode == 0:
                    print("{} exit with code:{}".format(p, p.exitcode))
                else:
                    job = self._jobs_on_procs.get(p.name)
                    if p.exitcode > 0:
                        print("{} with code:{} {}".format(p, p.exitcode, job))
                    else:
                        print("{} been killed with code:{} {}".format(p, p.exitcode, job))

                    result = {
                        "status": "failed"
                    }

                    self._out_queue.put(result)

    def _collect(self):
        # TODO: Spawn a collector proc
        while True:
            r = self._out_queue.get()
            self._out_stream.append(r)
            if len(self._out_stream) >= self._total:
                print("Total {} jobs done.".format(len(self._out_stream)))
                break

    def _serve(self):
        for job in self._in_stream:
            self._in_queue.put(job)

        for _ in range(self._workers_num):
            self._in_queue.put(None)

    def _monitor(self):
        running = 0
        while True:
            proc_name, job = self._run_queue.get()
            running += 1
            self._jobs_on_procs.update({proc_name: job})
            if running == self._total:
                break


class WorkerProcess(object):

    def __init__(self, worker_id, in_queue, run_queue, out_queue):
        self._worker_id = worker_id
        self._in_queue = in_queue
        self._run_queue = run_queue
        self._out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        self._work()
        print('worker - {} quit'.format(self._worker_id))

    def _work(self):
        print("worker - {0} start to work".format(self._worker_id))
        job = {}
        while True:
            job = self._in_queue.get()
            if not job:
                break

            try:
                proc = current_process()
                self._run_queue.put((proc.name, job))
                r = self._run_job(job)
                self._out_queue.put(r)
            except Exception as err:
                print('Unhandle exception: {0}'.format(err), exc_info=True)
                result = {"status": 'failed'}
                self._out_queue.put(result)

    def _run_job(self, job):
        time.sleep(job)
        return {
            'status': 'succeed'
        }


def main():

    jobs = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    procs_num = 3
    m = WorkersManager(jobs, procs_num)
    m.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```
worker - 0 start to work
worker - 1 start to work
worker - 2 start to work
Process TIMEOUT: Process-1 3
Process TIMEOUT: Process-2 6
Process TIMEOUT: Process-3 7
Total 5 jobs done.
```

You are probably aware of this, but due diligence requires that I mention that there are two excellent classes `multiprocessing.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` for doing what you want to accomplish. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776189/concurrent-futures-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3/60644649#60644649) for some comparisons.

**Further Explanation**

What is the point of using a `JoinableQueue`, which supports calls to `task_done`? *Usually*, it is so that you can be sure that all of the messages that you have placed on the queue have been taken off the queue and processed and the main process will not be terminating prematurely before that has occurred. But this could not work correctly in the code as you had it because you were giving your processes only `TIMEOUT` seconds to process its messages and then terminating the process if it was still alive with the possibility that messages were still left on its queue. This is what forced you to artificially issue extra calls to `task_done` just so your calls to `join` on the queues in the main process would not hang and why you had to post this question to begin with.

So there are two ways you could have proceeded differently. One way would have allowed you to continue using `JoinableQueue` instances and calling `join` on these instances to know when to terminate. But (1) you would not then be able to prematurely terminate your message processes and (2) your message processes must handle exceptions correctly so that they do not prematurely terminate without emptying their queues.

The other way is what I proposed, which is much simpler. The main process simply places on the input queue a special *sentinel* message, in this case `None`. This is just a message that cannot be mistaken for an actual message to be processed and instead signifies *end of file* or, in other words, a signal to the message process that there are no more messages that will be placed on the queue and it may now terminate. Thus, the main process just has to place in addition to the "real" messages to be processed on the queues, the additional sentinel message and then instead of doing a `join` call on the message queues (which are now only regular, non-joinable queues), it does `join(TIMEOUT)` on each process instance, which you will either find to be no longer alive because it has seen the sentinel and **therefore you know that it has processed all of its messages** or you can call `terminate` on the process if you are willing to leave messages on its input queue.

Of course, to be *really* sure that processes that terminated on their own really emptied their queue might require you to check their queues to see that they are indeed empty. But I assume that you should be able to code your processes to handle exceptions correctly, at least those that can be handled, so that they do not terminate prematurely and do something "reasonable" with every message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your solution and code snippet you pasted. it works like charming. while I still have a confusion on queue.join() before exit. I had same codebase which built on multiprocessing.Queue() as you do before. It need to invoke cancel_join_thread() before exit.

Comment: What is your confusion?

Comment: The confusion is on the queue.join() before exit at the end of run() func. It's here need to invoke the in_queue.join() and out_queue.join() here? If not and why?

Comment: The code snippet as below:

        self._in_queue.join()
        self._out_queue.join()
        return self._out_stream

Comment: See answer for a "Further Explanation."

Comment: Cool. Awesome explanation from U. I would handle the unhandle-excetpion in the WorkProcess. Thanks