# Pythonic way to use threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Recently I have been doing a lot of network or IO bound operations and using threads helps speed up the code a lot. I noticed that I have been writing code like this over and over again:

```
threads = []
for machine, user, data in machine_list:
  mythread = threading.Thread(target=get_info, args=(machine, user, data))
  mythread.start()
  threads.append(mythread)
  
for mythread in threads:
  mythread.join()
```

This feels somewhat repetitive. It works, but I suspect there is likely a more "Pythonic" way to write this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool), which has the same semantics as [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), but uses threads instead of processes.

You can do what you are currently doing more concisely like this:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool() # optionally pass the number of threads in the pool
res = pool.starmap_async(get_info, machine_list)
res.wait()
```

This is not exactly equivalent to your code since `ThreadPool` creates a fixed number of threads (by default equal to the number of available CPUs) and distributes work among them, but you can nonetheless pass the number you want (e.g. `ThreadPool(len(machine_list))`) to create exactly one for each item in the list.

Then you can also create a function to easily do this multiple times:

```py
def run_threads(func, arglist):
    ThreadPool(len(arglist)).starmap_async(func, arglist).wait()
```

Note: `.starmap_async()` is just one way to achieve this. There are multiple methods you can use. Take a look at the documentation for `Pool` linked above and choose the one you prefer.

Comment: This is definitely a reasonable way to do this, but important to note, it isn't exactly equivalent, since you are using a Pool.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, I have noted that part editing the answer.

Comment: Both multiprocessing and concurrent.futures provide good high level support for managing threads. Take a look here for a comparison of the two modules https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776189/concurrent-futures-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

In Python, there is an easy and simple approach to work with many threads.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

from tqdm import tqdm


def do_something(item):
    print(item)
    sleep(1)
    print(f"Finished {item}")


items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    for item in items:
        executor.submit(do_something, item)

# with progressbar:
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    list(tqdm(executor.map(do_something, items), total=len(items)))

print("finished")
```

Note: I tried others, but this is the only one that worked with Docker multi-threading on a single vCPU ( google cloud run environment )

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way would probably be to use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). The problem you have is exactly what `asyncio` was designed for. The net result is broadly the same as using threading. However, instead of threads though, you have tasks. And when a task is blocked, the executor will switch to a different task. However, the program will be single-threaded and so avoid the overhead caused by the GIL when switching between threads.

```py
import asyncio

async def get_info(machine, user, data):
    # NB. async declaration
    ...

async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(get_info(machine, user, data))
        for machine, user, data in machine_list
    ]
    done, _pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    
    # asyncio is more powerful in that it allows you to directly get results of tasks.
    # This is unlike threading, where you must use some form of signalling 
    # (such as a queue) to get data back from a thread. 
    results = {}
    for args, task in zip(machine_list, tasks):
        result = await task  # this gets the result immediately since you have 
        # already used asyncio.wait
        results[args] = result
task: (await task) for task in tasks}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The problem with this approach is that you'll have to start using asyncio-aware libraries and rewrite your own code to be asyncio-aware. Though to get started you can use [`asyncio.to_thread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread). It will run the given function in a separate thread,

```py
import asyncio

def get_info(machine, user, data):
    # NB. no async declaration
    ...

async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.to_thread(get_info, machine, user, data)
       for machine, user, data in machine_list
    ]
    done, _pending = asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

## `concurrent.futures`

If you're heavily invested in the threading model and switching to asyncio would be too much work, and having to learn all the new concepts would be too much of a barrier, then you can use [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_info(machine, user, data):
    ...

def get_info_helper(args)
    machine, user, data = args
    return get_info(machine, user, data)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(get_info_helper, machine_list))
```

Comment: Not sure how much OP is willing to dedicate to [function coloring](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/), but `asyncio` can be pretty annoying to integrate into existing code.